# Best way to unload delta data from DB2 transactional tables?

Tags: db2, etl, data-extraction

Sorry if this has been asked before. I am hoping to win some time this way :)

What would be the best way to unload delta data from a DB2 source database that has been optimized for OLTP? E.g. by analyzing the redo files, as with Oracle Logminer?
Background: we want near-realtime ETL, and a full table unload every 5 minutes is not feasible.
this is more about the actual technology behind accessing DB2 than about determining the deltas to load into the (Teradata) target.

Ie, we want to unload all records since last unload timestamp.

many many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [IBM InfoSphere Data Replication](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.idr.frontend.doc/pv_welcome.html?cp=SSEPGG_11.1.0).

Briefly:
There are 3 replication solutions: CDC, SQL & Q replication.
All 3 solutions read Db2 transaction logs using the same [db2ReadLog API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001673.html), which anyone may use for custom implementation. All other things like staging & transformation of the data changes got from logs, transportation and target application of data are different for each method.